# AND operation for Boolean array's elements

Tags: python, boolean

I have a variable length Boolean array as shown below:

```
ARR = [True, False, True, False,...]
```

Is there any simplest way (single line) to perform AND operation for all elements, as below?

```
ARR[0] and ARR[1] and ARR[2] and ARR[3] and ARR[*]...
```

Comment: try using the built-in `all()`. some thing like `if all(ARR): print "ALL are true"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a builtin, called `all`, which will `and` together all its arguments.  For example:

```
>>> ARR = [True, False, True, False,]
>>> all(ARR)
False
```

And:

```
>>> ARR2 = [True, True, True,]
>>> all(ARR2)
True
```

#### More

The argument to `all` need not be a list of booleans.  Anything can be used as long as python can evaluate it to true or false.  For example:

```
>>> all([True, 10, 'name'])
True
>>> all([True, 0, 'name'])
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the `and` operation done, it should return True if all the elements in the list are True. So this simple line will do:

```
print(False not in bool_list)
```

This line looks for a False in the given list, thus technically doing the `and` operation

Answer (score 0):

You would use a for loop:

```
a = true
for x in ARR:
    if !x:
        a = false
print(a)
```

Of course to do this in one line you could convert it into a function and call that.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to this question but if someone also wants to know how to "and" an array of `False` you can try the following:

```
if not sum([False, False, False, ...]):
    # enters this block when the array only contains False
else:
    # there is at least one True value in the array
```